# I don't understand a construction in Theorem 9.2 of Rudin

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Here is the theorem:
Let $r$ be a positive integer. If a vector space $X$ is spanned by a set of $r$ vectors, then $\dim X \leq r$.
Here is the proof of the theorem:
If this is false, there is a vector space $X$ which contains an independent set $Q = \{y_1,...,y_{r+1}\}$ and which is spanned by a set $S_0$ consisting of $r$ vectors.

Suppose   $0\leq  i < r$, and suppose a set $S_i$ has been constructed which spans $X$ and which consists of all $y_j$ with  $1\leq j\leq i$ plus a certain collection of $r - i$ members of $S_0$, say $x_1,...,x_{r-i}$.(In other words, $S_i$ is obtained from $S_0$ by replacing $i$ of its elements by members of $Q$, without altering the span).

I don't understand the construction of $S_i$ in details. Are the first mentioned $S_0$ and constructed $S_i$( when $i = 0$) the same ?
I also don't understand from what is composed for example $S_1$ ( I mean the elements of it.)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess you should read further, as it's seemingly only the introduction part of the construction.

Comment: By definition, $S_i$ contains $r-i$ members of $S_0$. So indeed the notation is consistent for $i=0$, since $S_0$ has $r=r-0$ members. 

$S_1$ contains $y_1$ and all except one element of $S_0$. You should convince yourself of the fact that it is possible to choose which element to remove so that $S_1$ still spans $X$. As @Berci notes, this construction is probably described in the book.

The end goal of the proof is the fact that $S_r$ is a set that spans $X$ and  consists of the elements $y_1, \ldots, y_r$. This leads to a contradiction (why?).

Answer (score -1):

$S_0$ is the same . there is used an induction. you should continue this process until you achieve the fact that $y_{r+1}$ becomes dependent. if you replace x by y you still get X spanned . pick one $x_j$.
$$x_j=\frac{y_i-\alpha_{i,1}x_1-\alpha_{i,2}x_2-...-\alpha_{i,j-1}x_{j-1}-\alpha_{i,j+1}x_{j+1}-...-\alpha_{i,r}x_r}{\alpha{i,j}}$$
Thus, we replace $x_j$ with $y_i$ to get $S_1$.